# Confusions in discretizing a momentum delta integral

Tags: momentum, integration, discrete, dirac-delta-distributions, lattice-model

I have an integral of the following form:

$$\int dk_{x}dk_{y}dk_{z}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\delta\left(\sqrt{k_{x}^{2}+k_{y}^{2}+k_{z}^{2}}-p\right)f(k)$$
There are two ways to convert it into discrete form:
$$ \int dk_{x}dk_{y}dk_{z}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\delta\left(\sqrt{k_{x}^{2}+k_{y}^{2}+k_{z}^{2}}-p\right)f(k)
= \int d\phi d\theta d|k|k^{2}sin(\theta)\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\delta\left(|k|-p\right)f(k)
= \int d\phi d\theta p^{2}sin(\theta)\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}f(k)|_{|k|=p}
= \sum_{k_{x}k_{y}k_{z}\ where|k|=p}\frac{1}{L^{2}}\frac{1}{2\pi}f(k)|_{|k|=p}$$

where  $$\int d\phi d\theta p^{2}sin(\theta)\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2}}=\int dS\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{L^{2}}\sum_{k_{x}k_{y}k_{z}\ where|k|=p}$$

The second way is:
$$ \int dk_{x}dk_{y}dk_{z}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\delta\left(\sqrt{k_{x}^{2}+k_{y}^{2}+k_{z}^{2}}-p\right)f(k)
= \int dk_{x}dk_{y}dk_{z}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\delta\left(\sqrt{k_{x}^{2}+k_{y}^{2}+k_{z}^{2}}-p\right)f(k)
= \int dk_{x}dk_{y}dk_{z}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\delta\left(g(k_{z})\right)f(k)
= \int dk_{x}dk_{y}dk_{z}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\sum_{i}\frac{\delta(k_{z}-k_{zi})}{|g'(k_{zi})|}f(k)
= \int dk_{x}dk_{y}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\sum_{i}(\frac{1}{|g'(k_{zi})|}f(k)|_{k_{z}=k_{zi}})
= \sum_{k_{x}k_{y}}\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{L^{2}}\sum_{i}(\frac{1}{|g'(k_{zi})|}f(k)|_{k_{z}=k_{zi}})
 $$

I am confused about which is the correct way, especially about the usage of L.

Comment: What is $g(k_z)$ in your second way?

Comment: @g(kz)is just an expression of all the terms in the parenthesis of delta function.

Comment: Not sure why is it just a function of $k_z$.

Comment: Is $f$ a function of the vector $\textbf k$ or of its magnitude $|\textbf k|$? Also I do not understand the notation after the last equal sign in the first method. How are you integrating the $\theta$ and $\varphi$ dependence of $f$ if it doesn't depend on $|\textbf k| only?

Comment: @Kiarash it is a function of kx,ky,kz. If we want to integrate kz, and kx ky can be treated as constants.

Comment: @John Donne. I didn't integrate $\theta$ and phi. I just turn it into the discrete form.